# Pulling Snowflake table into Dataframe

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I continue to get and error "ProgrammingError: 002003 (42502): SQL compilation error: Object 'Table' does not exist or not authorized. I am using the following code:

```
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
user = "user.name",
authenticator="externalbrowser",
warehouse = "ware house name",
database = "db name",
schema = "schema name"
)
cur.con.cursor()
sql = "select * from Table"
cur.execute(sql)
df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
```

When I execute the code in Jupyter Notebook the browser window opens and authenticates my creds but when it gets to the sql execute line the error rises and tells me that the table does not exist. When I open up Snowflake in my browser I can see that the table does exist in the correct warehouse, database and schema I have in my code.

Has anyone else ever experienced this? Do I need to authorize my user to be able to access this table via Python and Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Could you check the actual query sent to Snowflake in the [history page](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-history.html)? There is a chance the table name is case sensitive and requires wrapping with `SELECT * FROM "Table_name_here"`

Comment: I checked the history, it looks like most of them are failing. I tried wrapping the table name in double quotes and the script is still failing. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's likely your session doesn't have a role assigned to it (current role).
You can add the role in your list of connection session paramters,
e.g. add something like the following

```
role = 'RICH_ROLE',
```

You might want to consider setting a default role for your user.

```
ALTER USER userNameHere SET DEFAULT_ROLE = 'THE_BEST_ROLE';
```

docs link: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html

Also, when all else fails, use the fully qualified table name, note this won't help much if the role isn't set:

```
sql = "select * from databaseName.schemaName.TableName"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I tried this with my role it said that the role does not exist or not authorized. It does have "-" in the role name - could that have something to do with it? I also tried putting the entire "databaseName"."SchemaName"."Tablename" in the sql query

Comment: if you tried using the role, and could not, then you don't have access to it, so you'll need to speak with your administrator and/or follow your team's process to get the role.   If you use the webUI with the same username and role as your code, and can query the table in the webUI, but cannot in the code, then your current context in your code's session is not correct, something amiss with your connection parameters.

Comment: Rich - I had the wrong role listed as a variable. I now am able to access the table. Thanks for the help!